# A Django service giving Internal server error

Tags: python, django

I am running a web application developed in Django. When the appication is run, it is giving internal server error.

Here is the apache log

```
[Fri May 27 23:15:32 2016] [error] [client 203.110.245.243] mod_wsgi (pid=554): Target WSGI script '/home/randUser/DisCern/DisCern/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri May 27 23:15:32 2016] [error] [client 203.110.245.243] mod_wsgi (pid=554): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/randUser/DisCern/DisCern/wsgi.py'.
[Fri May 27 23:15:32 2016] [error] [client 203.110.245.243] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri May 27 23:15:32 2016] [error] [client 203.110.245.243]   File "/home/ankesh/DisCern/DisCern/wsgi.py", line 25, in <module>
[Fri May 27 23:15:32 2016] [error] [client 203.110.245.243]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri May 27 23:15:32 2016] [error] [client 203.110.245.243]   File "/home/ankesh/DisCern/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
[Fri May 27 23:15:32 2016] [error] [client 203.110.245.243]     django.setup()
[Fri May 27 23:15:32 2016] [error] [client 203.110.245.243]   File "/home/ankesh/DisCern/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 20, in setup
[Fri May 27 23:15:32 2016] [error] [client 203.110.245.243]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Fri May 27 23:15:32 2016] [error] [client 203.110.245.243]   File "/home/ankesh/DisCern/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
[Fri May 27 23:15:32 2016] [error] [client 203.110.245.243]     self._setup(name)
[Fri May 27 23:15:32 2016] [error] [client 203.110.245.243]   File "/home/ankesh/DisCern/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
[Fri May 27 23:15:32 2016] [error] [client 203.110.245.243]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Fri May 27 23:15:32 2016] [error] [client 203.110.245.243]   File "/home/ankesh/DisCern/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 98, in __init__
[Fri May 27 23:15:32 2016] [error] [client 203.110.245.243]     % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
[Fri May 27 23:15:32 2016] [error] [client 203.110.245.243] ImportError: Could not import settings 'DisCern.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named DisCern.settings
```

Here is the wsgi.py file

```
import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('~/DisCern/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/home/ankesh/DisCern/DisCern')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "DisCern.settings")
# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("/home/ankesh/DisCern/env/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

What can be the possible error?

Comment: is the settings file `'/home/ankesh/DisCern/DisCern/settings.py'`? if so you either need to append the folder containing the package to sys.path with `sys.path.append('/home/ankesh/DisCern')` or import the settings without reference to the package with `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")` (but not both)

Comment: I dont think it is wise to activate the virtualenv in the `wsgi.py` file. Instead either run the python interpreter from the virtualenv or set the virtualenv in your Apache/nginx config.

Comment: Please show Your Apache config

Comment: The error is most definitely going to be one of permissions. You hav probably made your wsgi.py readable by apache but not done so for the other files. Apache runs as a different user from ankesh and will not have access to the stuff in your home folder.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen  It worked. Thanks